# How to convert Eigen::Affine3f to Affine3d

Tags: point-cloud-library

I used pcl::TransformationFromCorrespondeces to get 3D transformation, but I want to convert the Affine3f result to Affine3d to facilitate my following process.

Answer (score 6):

I just found the answer. It's quite easy actually:

```
Eigen::Affine3f A;
Eigen::Affine3d B = A.cast<double>();
```